# ¿Por qué no se encuentra el módulo de "firebase"?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, typescript, vscode

El error me lo marca en la segunda línea, precisamente en la palabra "firebase" y no solo eso sino que en la linea 15 me marca como error la palabra response diciendo "is declared but its value never read" y por ultimo la palabra token en la linea 17 me marca error diciendo "parameter token implicitly has an 'any' type".

EL archivo es asi:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import * as firebase from "firebase";

@Injectable()
export class LoginService{

token: string;

constructor(private router: Router){}

login(email: string, password: string){
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(response => {
            firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(
                token=> {
                    this.token = token;
                }
            )
        }
    )
    this.router.navigate(["/"]);
}

getIdToken(){
    return this.token;
}
}
```

Pero no entiendo por qué si antes de escribir el codigo lo había instalado en la terminal usando npm install firebase --save y el mi archivo de package.json está en las dependencias. He reemplazado el from de firebase con @angular/fire y con firebase/app pero en ambas los errores de response y token persisten añadiendo como error la funcion auth().

Este es mi archivo de package.json:

```
{
  "name": "listado-personas",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.7.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.0",
    "firebase": "^9.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4",
    "rxfire": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1200.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.0.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "open": "^7.0.3",
    "jsonc-parser": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Y por ultimo, el error del import en la palabra "firebase" del from se refleja igualmente en mi archivo de app.components.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from  "firebase";



@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  titulo = 'Listado de personas';



constructor (){}


ngOnInit(): void {
  firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      })
    }
}
```

Tanto la apikey como el authDomain lo censuré al redactar esto, por lo que no se ven asi en mi archivo, por supuesto.

Comment: 0

Bienvenido@. Las publicaciones que son extensas y añaden información innecesaria, no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Por favor, te sugiero revisar como hacer un pregunta para comenzar a hacer preguntas mejores preguntas y la comunidad pueda ayudarte.

Comment: [Revisa la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?hl=es) y las notas y comentarios sobre versiones y demás. Por ejemplo, te dice que el estilo `import *` se usa sólo si tienes la versión 7 o anterior.

Comment: Eso es porque la versión 9 del sdk introduce varios breaking changes, debes leer la [guía de migración](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade). El link que proporcionó @A.Cedano también está desactualizado si lo lees en español, asegurate de cambiar a la versión en ingles.

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem he actualizado a version 9.0.0 y he hecho los imports correspondientes. Los errores de firebase, response y token ya no estan. Pero a cambio me aparece error en firebase.auth().currentUser que viene despues del cuerpo de response. ¿Cuál sería el código a corregir en este caso?

Comment: reemplaza `firebase.auth().currentUser` por `response.user`. Hay un ejemplo en la [documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password).

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es por la versión de firebase que se está usando. He probado a entrar en la carpeta ng_modules y he borrado la versión que habia de firebase. En mi caso, la 9.X, no sé exactamente cual era.

Asimismo he probado a usar el siguiente comando:

```
npm install firebase@7.24.0 angularfire2 --save
```

Con esta versión si me reconoce el import

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
```